# What is better? Normalized url or Absolute Url?

Tags: html, url, relative-path, absolute-path

In one of my app i have (a) base url (2) app folder. Like $base_url = 'http://www.mysite.com'
and $app_folder = '/myfolder', so now the root url for the app becomes 'http://www.mysite.com/myfolder'.

using this i can have absolute urls or relative/normalized urls for all the links in the application.

If my understanding is correct, if i use an absolute url, there will be a DNS lookup for the url and relative urls seems like use the already resolved DNS entry.

Is this entirely correct? and also, what should be better? absolute paths? or relative paths?

Thanks,
Anjan

Comment: I'd believe that all major browsers have a DNS cache.

Comment: I believe in root relative URLs e.g. if your current page is `http://www.mysite.com/path` then use `/path/to/page` rather than `to/page`

Answer (score 0):

- Your path are all absolute, when you begin a path with "/" it means it's absolute. So in your cas "/myfolder/toto.jpg" is the same as "www.mysite.com/myfolder/toto.jpg"
- I always use absolute path in web portals, if tomorrow you add url rewriting to your app, you'll have problem with relative path : if www.mysite.com/article.php?id=5 become www.mysite.com/categorie/subcategorie/shoes.html then your relative url will be broken.
- BUT : Don't worry about optimization too early, build your app as you think it's logical and natural, and then you'll think about details like making too much DNS query.

Comment: The whole `/article.php?id=5` becoming `/category/subcategory/shoes.html` problem will still be faced no matter the URL scheme that is used. To fix that, no matter absolute or relative link, you just need to make `article.php` act as a permalink that redirects to the page with rewriting.

Comment: www.mysite.com/article.php?id=5 -> www.mysite.com/categorie/subcategorie/shoes.html should not be broken, as the domain part of the urls are same.

Comment: @Shadower ,@ajan : if I use the url "myImage.jpg" (relative) in the page article.php, when I'll access to the page "www.mysite.com/categorie/subcategorie/shoes.html" the link will be broken because the browser will try to load "www.mysite.com/categorie/subcategorie/myImage.jpg" that doesn't exists.

Comment: You need to be accessing static files by their normal URL. I.E. you should always link to `/myImage.jpg`, whether or not you put `http://www.mysite.com` in front of it is up to you.

Comment: @Shadower856 So ? When did I say the opposite ? I just said that he shouldn't use relative url. And "normal url" means what for you ? I searched but coudn't find anything.

Comment: Normal, in this context, is the non-rewritten URL since images won't be rewritten from the relative (`/categorie/subcategorie/myImage.jpg`) to the actual path (`/myImage.jpg`), only pages will. Please post your rewrite rule to make the matter more clear on what will and won't be rewritten.